# Automatic update of an image in an Access DB following the file name in a filed

Tags: image, ms-access

in my DB for each record I have one external image that I would show in the DB mask.

I have the image in a stable path, and they have a name (like a code: G482) that is also put in a column of DB. So I would find a workaround so when I change the record the mask automatically show the related image.

Some suggestions?

Comment: Please provide context. Change record where? In a table? Form? What do you mean by *mask*? Illustrate your point with actual code, example data, and/or images.

Comment: @Parfait: In German, "Maske" = Form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way requires no code at all:

I assume that your form recordsource has a field `ImageName` which contains the file name of the image.

- Add an Image Control to your form
- Set its `ControlSource` to: `="D:\your_constant_path\" & [ImageName] & ".jpg"`
- Set the other image properties as needed

And that's all. The image will automatically display on its record if the image path is found.